# How to allow a single input in a "two-input input"?

Tags: python

So, I have this code that allows two inputs:

```
a, b = input("Enter a command: ").split()
if(a == 'hello'):
    print("Hi")
elif(a == 'color' and b == '3'):
    print("Changing color to 3")
    #example, doesn't actually change color
elif(a == 'color' and b == '2'):
    print("Changing color to 2")
else:
    print("invalid command")
```

And the "color 2"/"color 3" thing works. However, typing "hello", as it's
a single word, gives me this error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

So, how can I get around/fix this?
I hope this was formatted correctly and everything, thanks for taking the time to look at the question. I'm pretty new to python, so sorry if it's a simple fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know in advance how many arguments there are to the command, then you can not use this construct:

```
a, b = input("Enter a command: ").split()
```

You could try like this instead:

```
a, _, b = input("Enter a command: ").partition(' ')
```

Or, may I suggest to use more verbose variable names:

```
command, separator, arguments = input("Enter a command: ").partition(' ')
```

It will work for any number of arguments after the first 'command' word, because [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) is guaranteed to return a 3-tuple.

Comment: Can you explain why your solutions work? I'm not here to educate a 76K rep user, but answers should be explained :P

Comment: Added a doc reference.